# Magento-2 Email New Order Customer Data Variables not showing on email

Tags: email, magento2

Magento2, When a customer places an order, the email that gets sent to confirm what they ordered is messed up.

It looks setup correctly, and the funny thing is the Variable for the Order Number works fine, but the customer data is note coming through,

See attached,

Any idea's?

Thanks.
-O

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you look into vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html (core file), its used there as follows:

```
{{trans "%customer_name," customer_name=$order.getCustomerName()}}
```

you can use the same.